# Sending empty values to text file from php

Tags: php, html

Im trying to send a "rating" value from a php file to a text file. When im checking the console log it says that the value has been sent. Though when im checking the text file nothing has been added. But the text file itself said it was recently updated.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
<form name="Star" id="Star">    
    <div id="rating-area" class="shadow">   

    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb1" value="1" onclick="postStar()"/>
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb2" value="2" onclick="postStar()"/>
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb3" value="3" onclick="postStar()"/>
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb4" value="4" onclick="postStar()"/>
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb5" value="5" onclick="postStar()"/>

    </div>


</form>
<script>
function postStar() {
    var StarInput = $("#Star").val();   

    $.post("post.php", 
    {
        Star:StarInput
    },
    function(data, status){
        console.log("Data: " + data + " - Status: " + status);
    }
    );
}

</script>
```

And the post.php file:

```
<?php
echo "Hittar php-fil";  
if(isset($_POST['Star'])){

    $Star = $_POST['Star'];



    file_put_contents('textfile.txt', $Star . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

echo "Lgger in i txt-fil";  
}
?>
```

I can't really tell where the problems occurs.

Comment: Are the permissions correctly set on the file that you're trying to write results to? I think the file needs to be at least `666` (rw-rw-rw-) permissions to be able to write to it.

Comment: `var StarInput = $("#Star").val();` should be `var StarInput = $(this).val();` `#Star` is not holding any value, if I am correct.

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` to see what you get.

Comment: Sidenote: PHP forms default to GET if the method is omitted. You may want to change `<form name="Star" id="Star">` to `<form name="Star" id="Star" method="post">` although I'm not entirely certain if your JS will override it.

Comment: Permission is free for all for the textfile.txt.
Method did not work. Still gettin empty strings.
Starinput gave me an error, watch answer further below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="Star" id="Star">    
    <div id="rating-area" class="shadow">   

    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb1" data-value="1" />
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb2" data-value="2" />
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb3" data-value="3" />
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb4" data-value="4" />
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb5" data-value="5" />

    </div>


</form>
<script>

    // jQuery(document).on('click','div#rating-area img',function(e){
   jQuery('div#rating-area img').click(function(e){
        var val = jQuery(this).data('value') ;
        console.log(val) ;
        jQuery.post('post.php',{ Star : val },function(data,status){
            console.log('data:'+data+'/status'+status) ;
        }) ;
    }) ;

</script>
```

Comment: I did, but the console gave me the error message: TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined

Comment: woops yes it's an image you're clicking on, i'm not sure you can have a value... let's edit

Comment: Is it any other way around, than the one I've done, to give the image a value and send it to the textfile when it's "onclicked"?

Comment: 1)You could get rid of the value attributes of your images and change the calls to postStar to include the values `onclick='postStar(1);'` for example.  2)You could encode the value in the id of the image, and then extract it using postStar.  Many other ways as well.

Comment: Yep look at the edit. Not sure this was the problem but it's preferable to use data-value as it is not a invalid html attribute (data-* is always ok and good for using in JS)

Then onclick you just have to get the data-value with data('value') ; Also to clear the html part i prefer to bind the click event on JS instead as html part

Comment: I tried the new code but did not get any display in console log nor did textfile update.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't get any response. Hm, im using   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
Which is not the latest version. Is it critical?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, it doesn't support the .on('click' syntax, you can replace with .live('click' or update your jquery version

Comment: I've updated for a non-live click bind, wich in your case is perfectly right.